# Building Dictionary within Dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries that I need to transform:

```
my_dictionary = {}
my_array = [{'first': 'this'}, {'second': 'this'}]
```

What I want is to key `my_dictionary`, and then have sub-dictionaries that are equal to the items in `my_array`, like so:

```
my_dictionary = {'red' : {'first': 'this', 'second' : 'this'}}
```

What I had, in theory was:

```
for i in my_array:
    my_dictionary['red'] = dict(i.items())
```

but I'm getting an error of:

> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

I'm realizing though, it's probably because after the first iteration, I'm not creating a dictionary, I'm simply adding to it. Is there a way for me to pull the key from each item in `my_array` so that I can specify it more like:

```
for i in my_array:
    my_dictionary['red'][key_from_item_in_my_array] = my_array[key_from_item_in_my_array]
```

but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I'd bet you've got a variable called `dict` somewhere in your code.

Comment: What is array? Is it my_array?

Comment: Ahh, yea, I actually re-did this. and besically using the constructor approach, I just end up with only the last iterations data.  So its overwriting it for every iteration.  How can I add the key value pairs to the dictionary?

Comment: my apologies, editing now, yes array is my_array

Comment: Your code does not raise `TypeError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want to merge the dictionaries array into a single dictionary and then put that dictionary in another one.  The merge is easy:

```
new_dict = {}
for i in my_array:
    new_dict.update(i)
```

Now you can put your merged dictionary into your second one:

```
my_dictionary = {}
my_dictionary["red"] = new_dict
```

This produces:

```
my_dictionary = {'red': {'first': 'this', 'second': 'this'}}
```